# Rails routing wildcard for multiple models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, wildcard

I would like to add a wildcard for multiple models. I added a wildcard route to the end of my routes file:

`get '*city/*tag', to: 'cities#show'`

This works. However, I would like to add multiple wildcards like this:

```
get '*city/*tag', to: 'cities#show'
get '*city', to: 'cities#show', as: :city
get '*tag', to: 'articles#show'
```

I just don’t know how to fix this because it always points to the cities controller. Any idea how this could be fixed?

Every suggestion to put me in the right direction is welcome!

Rens

Answer (score 1):

The wildcard `*` matcher for Rails will match any portion of the URL, similar to a [Unix glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)). As such, when given the route `/foo`, your routes for both `*city` and `*tag` will match it. Rails simply picks the first route that matches, which is why you're seeing it always going to the cities controller.

You have a couple options:

1. Make your routes non-ambiguous. E.g.:

   ```
   get 'cities/*city', to: 'cities#show', as: :city
   get 'tags/*tag', to: 'articles#show'
   get '*city/*tag', to: 'cities#show'
   ```

   Is a route setup that is non-ambiguous, because the prefixes of `cities` and `tags` are matched first, before your wildcard routes. You could also do a more straightforward RESTful route structure.
2. Have your cities controller handle the case where `params[:city]` is *not* a city, and redirect it to the articles controller in that case. This blends routing logic into your controller logic, though, so while it's possible I'd strongly suggest you go with option 1 instead.

Hope that helps!